# mysqld: where is the query log file saved?

Tags: mysql, logging

i have executed this

> sudo mysqld --general_log

Where the log file is stored?

Regards

Javi

Comment: please tell us your configuration and how you installed MySQL (repository (deb, ...) or manual (by source, archive))

Comment: well I don't know exactly..I didn't installed it..Any way to know it?

Comment: Although this belongs on Serverfault, the querylog is usually stored in /var/log/apache but it can be edited in **your my.cnf** (usually /etc/mysql/my.cnf) to be another directory using the  `general_log` (used to be just `log`) keyword. If you didn't install it yourself, ask the person who did? Or find my.cnf on the harddisk...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please have a look in the folder `/var/log/mysql/`.

By default the `general_log_file` is `host_name.log`.

For more see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_general_log_file

Comment: I tried this: "sudo mysqld --general_log=1 --general_log_file=/tmp/foo" and it creates the file "foo" but it just has this: mysqld, Version: 5.1.41-3ubuntu12.9-log ((Ubuntu)). started with: Tcp port: 3306  Unix socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock. Time Id Command    Argument. After executing "sudo mysqld --general_log=1" I did a request to the server. I expected some information about the queries executed...